# How to use custom names in Options of Select tag?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

schema_fld is a list of objects and how can I display the custom names in Select tag.
I want to append values to the display string of the model. If the display string is 'Apple' then I want to display it as 'Fruit-Apple' in the UI.

I cannot use the (**str**)  method in models as it is being  used in other part of the application. I created a method in model 'domval_display' but calling that from html is not working.

```
 <table class='no_error'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Schema Fields</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %} {{ hidden }} {% endfor %} {{ form.schema_fld.errors.as_ul }}{{ form.schema_fld }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>


class SchemaFld(models.Model):
    schema_fld_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fld_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    schema = models.ForeignKey(TSchema, models.DO_NOTHING)

    def domval_display(self):
        return 'Fruit-'+str(self.fld_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(str(self.fld_name))


class MappingSetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       asset = kwargs.pop('asset', None)
       super(MappingSetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['schema_fld'].queryset =self.fields['schema_fld'].queryset.filter(schema_id=asset.src_schema.schema_id)

    class Meta:
        model = MappingSet
        fields = [ 'schema_fld']
        widgets = {
         'updated_by': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

Comment: Show your form.

Comment: If you have a `SchemaFld` instance called `s`, then `{{ s.domval_display }}` will display what you want. Note in your template you're using a form, but you're not showing the form here, so I'm not sure what you're expecting in that form. Also typecasting to `str()` for `self.fld_name` is redundant since `fld_name` is a CharField so by default fetching it returns a `str` type.

Comment: @dirkgroten I edited it now, please check

Comment: So what is the MappingSet model? Preumably `MappingSet.schema_fld` is a ForeignKey to SchemaFld?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs for ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) show, you need to define a custom field that implements the `label_from_instance` method and use it in your form.

```
class FruitModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.domval_display()    # or just do the string formatting here


class MappingSetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    schema_fld = forms.FruitModelChoiceField(queryset=SchemaFld.objecst.none())
```

Comment: Thank you so much :-) it worked. I'm extremely sorry not able to upvote as my reputation is less. Thanks again